# Ways to enable isZoneRedundant flag in existing region of CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Can anyone advise an approach to enable isZoneRedundant for the existing CosmosDB region?

I think one way could be (say we need it in region A):

- Add another region B
- Remove region A
- Add region A with isZoneRedundant enabled
- Remove region B

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 3):

The only way to make a region zone redundant after it has already been added to the account is to add a second region, then do a regional failover to that second region, remove the original write region, add it back with zone enabled, then fail over again to the newly added region.

Regional failover is a POST operation so must be done with PowerShell or CLI script. There are examples for [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/manage-with-cli#trigger-manual-failover) and for [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/manage-with-powershell#trigger-manual-failover). These samples also have examples for adding and removing regions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your own and Mark Brown's answer is correct

Here is the formal MS doc for it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/high-availability

> Zone redundancy can only be configured when adding a new region to an Azure Cosmos account. For existing regions, zone redundancy can be enabled by removing the region then adding it back with the zone redundancy enabled. For a single region account, this requires adding a region to temporarily fail over to, then removing and adding the desired region with zone redundancy enabled.

A note for Terraform users. The terraform plan won't even notice the change/adding of the zone_redundant = true parameter.
I thought something was wrong but it probably should error instead of showing no change.
You can do the same operation via terraform by running multiple applies to add, remove, re-add with zone_redundant = true.
Or do it manually and then do a terraform apply -refresh-only (note: I haven't tried this for zone_redundant, I was using for geo_locations)

Comment: This is supposed to be a comment on Mark's post but Im unable to comment yet.